# Need a keyboard with specific keys

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Okay, I've seen the webpage that shows you how to enter a decimal key on the number pad, but that's pretty complicated for one button, and the problem I have involves multiple buttons. See, I have a program that involves typing in functions like "x + 5". My problem right now is that the user has to go through three different keyboards just to enter that kind of function. I need to know if it's possible to set up a keyboard that will have specific keys in it. Is there a way to do this that's simpler than the decimal key method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom keyboard if none of the apple keyboards toots your flute.

The easiest way to do this is to create a view and add lots of buttons with their own titles and background images and, most importantly, actions. You'll also need a delegate.

To be more official, there are numerous online tutorials (and lots of SO questions).

Comment: Okay, how would I go about doing that? Do you know of a tutorial that I can use to do this?

Comment: @RaysonK - I've never needed to do this, so I cannot recommend any particular tutorial, but there are lots out there so look around for one that you like. I recommend you search for "calculator keypads" since they may be more the flavour of what you're after.