# Does apple allow any customized keyboards?

Tags: ipad

I'm sorry if this is a "duh" question, but this is sort of compounded with  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286886/need-a-keyboard-with-specific-keys). I've figured out that I need a custom view that basically mimics the virtual keyboard on the iPad, but with a different set of keys (like both numbers and letters). Here's the issue: this app is something that will be sold, so what I'm wondering is whether Apple allows custom keyboards that just mimic the regular keyboard.

Comment: Chances tell that no, it would modify system behavior, and confuse users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. As of iOS 4, you can set the `inputView` property of any `UIResponder` (like a `UITextField`) to your own custom view, and the system will display that view at the bottom of the screen in place of the system keyboard whenever that view gets first-responder status.

Comment: Oh, I see. I've looked at other posts mentioning what you said, but I didn't know that it specifically did that. Thanks!